# How can i handle memory error on html file?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have this kind of code

```
URL = r"C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\html.html"
html_report_part1 = open(URL, 'r', encoding="UTF-8").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part1, "html.parser")
```

and its return this kind of error:

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> MemoryError

Comment: MemoryError: Is the file large? Try to read it line by line?

Comment: Please add the füll stacktrace.

Comment: What was the original error? Is the html file large? There may be an html attack in the file. Is it small enough to inspect? Will it show in the browser?

Comment: The file is actually quite big. It weigh around 200mb

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
URL = r"C:\Users\jarze\PycharmProjects\CSV-modifier\venv\html.html"
html_report_part1 = open(URL, 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
html_text = ''
for line in html_report_part1.readlines():
    html_text += line
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Hey, your code seems to be working but it's 4 hours from when I start to execute it and it's still in progress :(